# Debian fails to boot after installing xfce 4.10, "lp: driver loaded but no device found" error

Tags: debian, boot

I decided to install xfce 4.10 on wheezy. However after rebooting I am getting stuck at some screen beginning with the line"

```
lp: driver loaded but no device found
```

Thing is, I can't do anything at this point.

Does anyone have an idea on what the problem might be an how to solve it?

[image: I added a pic if the screen]

Comment: lp is the printer, make sure the lp daemon is running and you've configured your printer. Try to unplug your printer, if attached.

I got this information by googling "lp: driver loaded but no device found" boot debian

Sources [here][1]
Hope it helps.

[1] http://forums.justlinux.com/showthread.php?30145-Printer-won-t-print-aren-t-they-supposed-to

Comment: these two could help you, too
http://board.issociate.de/thread/29915/Cant-Print.html
http://www.murga-linux.com/puppy/viewtopic.php?t=18205

Note: If any of these helped, please write a solution to this thread :)

Comment: Oh but i've nerver had a printer. I'm kind of new to Linux so sorry if im describing the problem badly. There are more lines, the last beeing "ieee80211 phy0: brcms_opt_bss_info_changed: arp filtering: enable true, count 1 (implement)". Thing is this screen always popped up but only for a second and with only a few lines.

Comment: OK. The printer (lp0) is not the problem. Neither is the wireless network card (wla0). So forget about them for now. Are you saying you had a functional Debian installation, then you installed Xfce and now it hangs upon boot?

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
alias parport_lowlevel parport_pc
```

and adding `parport_pc`, `lp` and `parport` modules to `/etc/modules`

```
echo "parport_pc" >> /etc/modules
echo "parport" >> /etc/modules
echo "lp" >> /etc/modules
```

Comment: Thx, but i cant even reach a terminal.. Any key combination that might help me?

Comment: Pressing esc repeatedly on boot? Please google that, i don't know right now